# Not able to create Search Service Application on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

When I try to create `Search Service Application` I got following error.

> Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service
>   Application.   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The timer job
>   completed, but failed on one or more machines in the farm. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobAsyncResult.End() at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplication.ProvisionInstances()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.Provision()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Provision()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminUtils.UpdateIgnoreSPUpdatedConcurrencyException(String
>   description, SearchAdminUtilsUpdateDelegate updateDelegate,
>   SearchAdminUtilsRefreshObjectDelegate refreshObjectDelegate) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.CreateSearchApp()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ProvisionSearchServiceApplication()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigurationJobDefinition.ExecuteTimerJob()

Answer (score 1):

This usually means your timer service isn't started on all servers or it's using the wrong account.

- Goto each server, go to Start-> Run... -> services.msc
- Find "SharePoint Timer Service" and make sure it's started.
- Also make sure the Timer service is running as the farm account.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check

- Make Sure SharePoint Timer and Admin Service is running on all server in the farm
- Start the Search service from services console on the server where you are configuring the search service.
- Make sure timer service running under the farm admin.
- may be try to reboot the server or sometime clear the config cache fix the issue.

http://www.ericharlan.com/timber-job-completed-failed-one-machines-farm/

also check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8f76da96-6ed3-45e3-a45d-d01c9973945c/timer-job-completed-but-failed-on-one-or-more-machines-in-the-farm?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below things :
Go to Start-> Run -> services.msc and make sure SharePoint Timer and Admin Service is running on all server in the farm. Note : Make sure the Timer service is running as the farm account.
If SharePoint Timer and SharePoint Admin service already started, then restart both services.
Do iisreset in each server. (Go to command prompt with Run as Administrator -> type iisreset -> press enter key)

You can also refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f76da96-6ed3-45e3-a45d-d01c9973945c/timer-job-completed-but-failed-on-one-or-more-machines-in-the-farm?forum=sharepointadminprevious

For more information on [SharePoint Consulting](http://www.binaryrepublik.com) and [Office 365 Consulting](http://www.binaryrepublik.com) visit us at www.binaryrepublik.com